# Namespace accessors Vs. "Using" accessors

Tags: c#, .net

Theoretical question: is it any difference between doing this:

```
using System;
...
var foo = new String("foo");
```

and this:

```
var foo = new System.String("foo");
```

DLL loading? A performance difference?

Mainly, my doubt is what's the best code practice in this situation?

Comment: If you don't use "using" you have to use always the full qualified name, including console.write...

Comment: Using is good code practice. so you don't have to use full name always. I don't think so there is any performance difference over here, it is just good code practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has no effect on performance or loading.

It can affect IDE performance, though -- if you use a `using` directive it adds places that the IDE has to look to resolve Intellisense, for example. This isn't a reason not to use them, but may be a reason to keep them to a minimum, and to avoid unused `using` directives.

As a coding practice, a `using` directive can potentially lead to confusion if you have similarly named classes in different namespaces.  For example, say you're creating a to-do application that has key objects called Tasks, but you're also doing some threading stuff using Threading.Tasks.  You don't want to use a `using` directive there.

Comment: Thank you! that was the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 9):

No, they'll be compiled to absolutely identical IL.

The [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sf0df423.aspx) (there's no such term as "namespace accessor") is *just* a way of telling the C# compiler that it should look in that namespace when trying to resolve simple names to fully-qualified ones.

(Of course both will actually fail to compile as there's no `String(String)` constructor in .NET, but that's a different matter.)

Note that using the built-in alias `string` is identical to using the `System.String` type too - it really is just an alias. For example:

```
// Just one type!
string x = new String(new char[10]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Same thing. Use any one you like more. I use `using`, and fallback to full names when name collision occurs.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said there is no performance benefit. The one benefit to not using using is avoiding namespace ambiguity. Say you have two different types of Pages, one that refers to a page on your site while the other refers to a page in a book. They are two discrete objects with different properties. In this case you would have to write out the whole namespace to be able to distinguish which type of Pages you were referring to.